# Sending data to and from two applications?

Tags: javascript, c, communication

I'm trying to write a test application for hardware and it needs to be webbased however the actual program for controlling the hardware is already made.

I made a webpage with html and javascript but i need to send data between these two applications, the applications both run on the same machine. I tried looking on the web but I cant figure it out. If anyone has an example or a direction for me to look at/in I would appreciate it.

Comment: is embedding a webserver in the native controlling program an option?

Comment: I would prefer not to because I made the webpage dynamic so it isn't fixed to a certain set of hardware and I did not make the control program

Comment: The application should stay aways reading from a **PIPE** file like when an app is listening from a socket. I this link http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html you can find the way to do that in C ( to read from PIPE ) from your web applciation you can append text to this file.

Comment: I cant use the pipe() function do I need a header file?